# PG DDL event trigger does not work properly

Tags: postgresql, eventtrigger

I am trying to intercept a CREATE TABLE by an event trigger in PostgreSQL, to forbid the creation of table that does not comply to some naming rules. My code is as follow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION e_ddl_create_table_func()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    obj record;    
BEGIN
   FOR obj IN SELECT * 
              FROM   pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() 
              WHERE  command_tag in ('CREATE TABLE')
   LOOP
        if  NOT  obj.object_identity LIKE 't?_%' ESCAPE '?'
        THEN
           raise EXCEPTION 'The table name must begin with t_';
        end if;
   END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER trg_create_table ON ddl_command_end
WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE TABLE')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE e_ddl_create_table_func();
```

When I try with:

```
CREATE TABLE t_toto3 (i INT)
```

I have systematically the following error:

> ERROR: The table name must begin with t_
> CONTEXT:  fonction PL/pgSQL e_ddl_create_table_func(), ligne 11 à RAISE

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3):

Per [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-event-triggers.html#PG-EVENT-TRIGGER-DDL-COMMAND-END-FUNCTIONS), `object_identity` is schema-qualified. It will be coming in as `'public.t_toto3'` in your example (unless you have a very nonstandard setup with some other default schema); you can get only the table component by passing it through [parse_ident()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.13.1.1.1) and extracting the 2nd item. (Note the extra parens around the final parse_ident() so that the array lookup is parsed correctly.)

```
testdb=# select 'public.t_toto3' LIKE 't?_%' ESCAPE '?';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)

testdb=# select parse_ident('public.t_toto3');
   parse_ident    
------------------
 {public,t_toto3}
(1 row)

testdb=# select (parse_ident('public.t_toto3'))[2] LIKE 't?_%' ESCAPE '?';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Alternatively, [parse_ident](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.13.1.1.1) could be used to split the name into schema a table name

Answer (score 0):

yes it works with parse_ident. The solution is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION e_ddl_create_table_func()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    obj record;    
BEGIN
   FOR obj IN SELECT * 
              FROM   pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() 
              WHERE  command_tag in ('CREATE TABLE')
   LOOP
        if  NOT  (parse_ident(obj.object_identity))[2] LIKE 't?_%' ESCAPE '?'
        THEN
           raise EXCEPTION 'The table name must begin with t_';
        end if;
   END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER trg_create_table ON ddl_command_end
WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE TABLE')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE e_ddl_create_table_func();
```